# How to sort a dataframe by a multiindex level?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe with a multiindex with various data in it. Minimal example could be this one:

```
elev = [1, 100, 10, 1000]
number = [4, 3, 1, 2]
name = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([name, elev, number], 
                                 names=('name','elev', 'number'))
data = np.random.rand(4,4)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=idx)
```

Now I want to sort if by its elevation or number. Seems like there's an inbuilt function for it: [`MultiIndex.sortlevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.sortlevel.html), but it just sorts the MultiIndex, and I can't figure out how to make it sort the dataframe along the index too.

`df.columns.sortlevel(level=1)` gives me a sorted Multiindex

```
(MultiIndex([('foo',    1, 4),
             ('baz',   10, 1),
             ('bar',  100, 3),
             ('qux', 1000, 2)],
            names=['name', 'elev', 'number']),
 array([0, 2, 1, 3], dtype=int64))
```

but trying to apply it with `df.columns = df.columns.sortlevel(level=1)` or `df = ...` just gives me `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 2 elements` or turns the df into the sorted multiindex. The keywords `axis` or `inplace` I'm used to for similar actions aren't supported in `sortlevel`.

**How do I apply my sorting to my dataframe?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
print (df)

name         foo       baz       bar       qux
elev        1         10        100       1000
number         4         1         3         2
0       0.009359  0.113384  0.499058  0.049974
1       0.685408  0.897657  0.486988  0.647452
2       0.896963  0.831353  0.721135  0.827568
3       0.833580  0.368044  0.957044  0.494838
```

Comment: I really, really hate it, how `columns` and `index` can sometimes be used interchangeably, and sometimes all hell breaks loose if you mix them up.

Comment: I've deleted my comments. It did not change the order, just some merge went wrong before that got me `name`, `elev` and `number` mixed up. I thought I had tested that, but apparently, I overlooked something...